# What do the red areas on Titans mean?

Tags: titanfall

What are these big red areas that appear on enemy Titans? They seem to only appear when a Titan's shields have gone down.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The red areas on the Titans are weak-spots; they appear when an enemy Titan's shields have been taken down. Hitting the weak-spot with a weapon (even a pilot weapon) will do extra damage to the Titan.

[image]